# lookups that span relationship. - Do all my model names need to have first capital letter

Tags: python, django, model

So I am currently learning about querysets and models in django. I was guided to this [article](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) from SO which states

> Lookups that span relationships
>
> Django offers a powerful and intuitive way to “follow” relationships
>   in lookups, taking care of the SQL JOINs for you automatically, behind
>   the scenes. To span a relationship, just use the field name of related
>   fields across models, separated by double underscores, until you get
>   to the field you want.
>
> This example retrieves all Entry objects with a Blog whose name is
>   'Beatles Blog':
>
> > > > Entry.objects.filter(blog__name='Beatles Blog') This spanning can be as deep as you’d like.
>
> It works backwards, too. To refer to a “reverse” relationship, just
>   use the lowercase name of the model.

Now in my case my models are already created using lowercase. Should I be going back and capitalizing the first character in the name of the model ?

Comment: No you dont need to, but you may want to to follow pep8 naming conventions

Answer (score 0):

Capitalizing class names is a PEP8 recommendation, not a requirement.

In case of Django models, it should not affect your table names and should be safe to do; however, it will not have any functional effect, it is only a style improvement